# JQueryUI adding an image in option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

Firstly, I've tried to find a select menu plugin for jquery that to be able to render images in the options.
I found such one but it is not updated long time ago and I am afraid it is not supported any more. So I am trying to develop my one.

So I am trying to create a JQuery UI Select menu and I want to add an image in the option.

And After that, I build my select and for each option I add image src data as additional attribute. After the loading of jquery UI select menu I want to setup the images.

I render on the server

```html
<select id="CarId2" name="CarId2">
    <option value="volvo" data-imagesrc="~/Plugins/Cars/Content/Images/volvo.png">Volvo</option>
    <option value="bmw" data-imagesrc="~/Plugins/Cars/Content/Images/bmw.png">BMV</option>
</select>
```

On Load I am trying to read the options of jqueryui select menu and to update the content of the item but ... I cannot even load the option item.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#CarId2").selectmenu();
  var options = $("#CarId2").selectmenu("option");

  for (item in options)
  {
    console.log(item);
  }
});
```

Can someone help me how to load the option of ui select menu and update its content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look to [selectmenu custom render](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/selectmenu/custom_render.html) you make do something like:

```js
$(function () {
  $.widget( "custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
      var li = $( "<li>" ),
          wrapper = $( "<div>", { text: item.label } );

      if ( item.disabled ) {
        li.addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
      }

      $( "<span>", {
        style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
        "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
      }).appendTo( wrapper );

      return li.append( wrapper ).appendTo( ul );
    }
  });

  $("#CarId2")
  .iconselectmenu()
  .iconselectmenu( "menuWidget")
  .addClass( "ui-menu-icons avatar" );
});
```

```css
/* select with CSS avatar icons */
option.avatar {
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.avatar .ui-icon {
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<select name="CarId2" id="CarId2">
    <option value="volvo" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3e04a46e85ad3e165d66f5d927eb609?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">John Resig</option>
    <option value="bmw" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e42b1e5c7cfd2be0933e696e292a4d5f?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">Tauren Mills</option>
    <option value="3" data-class="avatar" data-style="background-image: url(&apos;http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bdeaec11dd663f26fa58ced0eb7facc8?d=monsterid&amp;r=g&amp;s=16&apos;);">Jane Doe</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`_renderItem` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-_renderItem) of the `selectmenu` widget.
The function is responsible for the rendering of the elements in your select menu, and gives you the ability to create the items the way you want.

```
.selectmenu({
    ...
    _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        // Create the list item
        var li = $('<li>')
        // Create the image
        var img = $('<img>')
            .attr('src', $(item.element).data('imagesrc'))

        // append the img to the list item
        img.appendTo(li)

        // append the list item to the menu and return the item
        return li.appendTo( ul );
    }
    ...
})
```